# Perform a few custom async validations with class-validator

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I would like to have the following dto:

```
export class SetEntryPasswordDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @Validate(EntryBelongsToUser)
    @Validate(EntryIsNotLocked)
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsNumber()
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Validate(PasswordMatchValidator)
    @Matches(EValidator.PASSWORD, { message: 'password is not strong enough' })
    password: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    confirmPassword: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    passwordHint?: string;

    @IsNumber()
    userId: number;
}
```

The problem with it is that I need to do a couple of async validations and I would like to use the class-validator lib for this.

My question is: if I do this like in the code snippet above, can I be sure that the first one to complete is `EntryIsNotLocked`? If not then how to make those validation execute in order?

Thank you.

Additional information:

Seems like there's a bit of information that is of importance.

The `EntryBelongsToUser` and `EntryIsNotLocked` are the ValidatorConstraint classes. For instance, one of them looks as follows:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'EntryIsNotLocked', async: false })
@Injectable()
export class EntryIsNotLocked implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(
        private readonly entryService: EntryService,
    ) {}

    public async validate(val: any, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
        // here goes some validation logic
    }

    public defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments): string {
        return `Unauthorized to execute this action`;
    }
}
```

The second one looks exactly the same. So the question is can I guarantee the order by setting the `async` option of the `ValidatorConstraint` decorator to `false` for both of them?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't be sure of the sequential order of async functions. Thet's why you have `validateSync` method in class-validator package. You can use the `validateSync` method instead of the regular `validate` method to perform a simple non async validation.

See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator#synchronous-validation) for reference.

Comment: Ah, really?! I didn't know that, thank you! I've done a few tests yesterday and seems like the order remained, but those tests were not reliable enough, anyway I suspected something like that. Lemme check it, please.

Comment: Damn it...does it mean that I'm unable to use a couple of validators that need to query the DB? I read the doc but I still don't get it.

Comment: I've edited my question adding some more info, would you please have a look?